# Get IP address in a string

Tags: php, regex, search

I'm looking for some sort of PHP-code to scan my `/var/log/secure` to filter breakin attempts. Below are just some examples of strings that need to be searched and get the IP address ONLY. I'm using `0.0.0.0` as an example of an IP address and not the actual IP.

```
Failed password for invalid user admin from 0.0.0.0 port 3108 
Invalid user ubnt from 0.0.0.0
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: you can try with the fopen() function

$handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r");

https://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Do you want to simply store any IP addresses found in that file?

Comment: Include code that you have used to try and solve the problem.  Use proper formatting too.  This will help others help you.

Comment: $log = file_get_contents('/var/log/secure'); ... but you might need to execute the script with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information provided by the OP in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856609/get-ip-address-in-a-string/29856791?noredirect=1#comment47862839_29856791), I decided to redo my answer. So;

```
$file=file_get_contents("/var/log/secure");
$lines=explode("\n",$file);
$accepted=array();
$fail=array();
$r="/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/";
foreach($lines as $line){
  //try to get the ip
  $t=array();
  preg_match($r,$line,$t);
  $ip=$t[0];
  if(strpos($line,"Accepted password")!==FALSE){
    //Successfull login
    $accepted[]=$ip;
  }
  else{
    //failed login attempt
    $fail[]=$ip;
  }
}
```

Now `$accepted` contains all the IP's who logged in successfully, and `$fail` all those who did not.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks again for your help but a few code problems. file_get_content missing "s", line 12 had "===" changed it to "==", and I get an error on line 10 and 11:

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: t in test_ip.php on line 10
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: t in test_ip.php on line 11


Other than that I think were getting close... I really appreciate all your help with this.

Comment: Here ya go. The `===` was intentional, this is because `0` evaluates to `FALSE` when it should be `TRUE`

Comment: I put the "===" back but still get the line 10 and 11 errors, "Undefined variable: t".

Comment: It should be fixed now

Comment: Now I get: PHP Parse error:  

"syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/spfx/test_ip.php on line 14"

I guess because the ";" was missing on line 13. I put the ";" on line 13 and now I get IPs but also get this error:

"PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in test_ip.php on line 13".

Comment: Thank You --- Thank You --- Thank You VERY MUCH... I got it working... I change the preg_match line to: "if (preg_match($r,$line,$t)) {" and all is good so far as I can tell... Thank You AGAIN... :)

Comment: Damn... Just when I thought I got it I don't... I have one machine with PHP 5.4.16, Works Great... I have 2 other machines running PHP 5.1.6 and get:

 "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in test_ip.php on line 11"

I know the quick answer here is "update PHP" but if I try I get:

"No Packages marked for Update"

The one that works is running "Centos 7.0.1406" the others running "Centos 5.9 and 5.11"

Comment: I hope it works now, I forgot a `;`. If it still doesn't work, I don't know the answer either. You might then get an answer if you post a new question.
Anyway, glad I could help you a bit.

Comment: I caught the missing ";" and fixed it.It's a very odd issue and seems to be a problem with the strpos but I've used that for years and have working programs with that. Since it works on Centos 7 and my other machines are still on Centos 5 I think it's long overdue to upgrade/replace those older machines. Again, I really appreciate all the help on this...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow.

What you're looking for, is `preg_match_all` in combination with the correct regex.

```
$subject=file_get_contents("/var/log/secure");
$pattern="/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/";
preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches);
```

After this, `$matches` will contain a list of all IPs in the document.

---

BTW, include the code you've tried so far in your question.

Comment: WOW... I'm really rusty at PHP... Guess I'm a dinosaur at this. I'm still old school and just can figure how to get the IP address out of $matches[0]. I also need to skip any lines without an IP and any lines containing "Accepted password for (username)".

Thanks...

Comment: @InTitusville, this snippet fills `$matches` with all IP-address in your file. It doesn't do anything with lines that don't contain an IP. So it will ignore lines like `Accepted password for SZenC` because it does not contain an IP. It also doesn't care about other information on a given line.
I how this helps you.

Comment: What you say sound like what I need but being so behind in PHP what I need to know is how to get the IP data out of $matches. Is there a way to read line by line the IPs and is there a way to also check each line in the secure file for "Accepted password" and log those IPs in a different maches array? Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

This is the PHP script I use to parse my logs

```
$file=fopen("/var/log/secure", "r");
$ipDateArray=array();
$i=0;
while($line=fgets($file)){
    $dateString='';
    $ip='';
    if(preg_match("/failed/i",$line)){
        $lineArr=preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
        if(count($lineArr)==15){
            $dateString=$lineArr[0]." ".$lineArr[1]." ".$lineArr[2];
            $ip=$lineArr[10];
            $ipDateArray[$ip]=$dateString;
        } 

    }
    unset($ip);
    $i++;
}
```

Of course you will have to modify the structure a bit. The idea is I parse line by line looking for the keyword `failed` using `preg_match` and splitting (sort of like explode function) the string into array entries.

Since the pattern of entry for the logs files are nearly identical, you would simply access the same index of the array to get your IP. In my case `$lineArr[10]` holds the IP address for each entry in the log file for failed attempts.

Hope this helps and gives you a sense of idea on how to parse your logs.

Comment: Kind of helps. In my examples you can see 3 different lines and there are many other error message in the /var/log/secure file but I just need to pull the IP address and I don't care about what's on the rest of the line. some lines don't have an IP address so I just want to skip them and skip any lines containing "Accepted password for (username)".

Comment: I played around with this and got it working and seems to have what I need except it only pulls the IP from a "failed" line. I need all IP address except for lines containing "Accepted password for (username)". It's really close to what I need. 

Thanks for you help

Comment: WEIRDNESS.... This code works fine on my Centos 6 but doesn't work on centos 5. Rather than getting an IP I get "Connection". I searched the file for connection I get:


Apr 19 08:31:26 MyMachine sshd[6213]: Connection closed by 0.0.0.0


Down the file I have a line also using "failed" and connection but it's the same on both systems. Can't figure it out...
fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]

Comment: Yeah it sounds to be like there are different lines that you are trying to extract IP addresses from. I would suggest fixing the preg_match and just doing a var_dump of the array after splitting to see what indexes the IP address is at and if any you need to sanitize the string.